# MATLAB functions with persistent state

Tags: performance, matlab, persistence

I have a function where a lot of the work can be precomputed. The precomputation takes around 2000 microseconds and produces five arrays, the largest of which has length 360919, so clearly it is impractical to include them in the source code.

After precomputing, the function takes around 70 microseconds, so I get about a 30x speedup by doing the precomputation. I need to call this function millions of times (as part of a Monte Carlo algorithm) so it's obviously beneficial to have it run as fast as possible.

What is the best way to precompute the necessary arrays? At the moment I'm looking at the following options

1. Use persistent variables, and precompute them the first time the function is called.
2. Use global variables, and initialize them before calling the function.
3. Use a class, and precompute the arrays when the object is initialized.

All of these have some level of overhead, compared to the obvious but non-composable solution of inlining everything so that the local variables and precomputed variables are in the same workspace.

Is there another solution I've missed, that has less overhead than the above methods, but retains composability? Is the best solution just to drop into C?

Comment: I am pretty fine with matlab's object-oriented programming. This part of the language is reach enough to do the most of job. So my choice is the number three.

Comment: OOP probably increases running time. I would go for (1) or (2)

Comment: Do the persistent variables exist in c++, python or fortran? If not, it could be bad from the algorithmic point of view: it's not good to produce algorithms which are language dependent. How would you solve this problem in other languages?

Comment: @freude in Python/C++/Java I'd use a class. However, OOP is slow in Matlab. I've implemented both the persistent variable and OOP solutions, and the OOP version takes around 33% additional time. My concern is to get this going as fast as possible while maintaining composability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility, which I use quite often: use an auxiliary script (m-file) instead of a function. The main script does the precomputing and then calls the auxiliary script.

The auxiliary script has visibility of all variables defined in the calling script, so you don't need global or persistent variables, which probably introduce some overhead in terms of running time.

Of course, you need to take care that the variables in the auxiliary script do not overwrite anything they shouldn't in the main script. That is, you need to prevent clashes in the names of the variables between the two scripts.

Comment: Not a bad idea. Not very composable, but better than sticking everything in one file.

Comment: I'm going to accept this because I just implemented it, and it's nearly ten times faster than the next-fastest solution (using persistent variables). I'd love to know what causes the slowdown - whether it's function call overhead, or something to do with the persistent variables. My code is now a filthy mess (everything is inlined and my variables are called things like `rank__` and `i__` so that I don't get name collisions, but at least it's fast!

Comment: I'm curious to see the actual code here. The `persistent` solution should be pretty fast too; there are tons of persistents in my code and I'm wondering if that's causing issues now.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Perhaps the speed-up has something to do with memory management: with the auxiliary script you overwrite the variables in each iteration, whereas with a function Matlab probably clears all variables on exiting the function, and then in the next iteration it has to reallocate. I mean not the persistent variables, of course, but the function's internal variables